# Complex record comparison removing duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am trying to compare records within the same table, so I am selecting the records by fields ID, X, Y and Z, and matching them where X, Y and/or Z are equal. In order to do the compare I am joining the table to itself then comparing each record with each other record

My problem is that if I have a record A that matches 10 other records B-K on field Z, it will then list each of the records B-K as it finds them in the second instances of the table, alongside A that it finds in the first instance of the table. Then when it finds each one of B-K in the first instance of the table, it will then list each matching record again. In this case there are 11 records that match on field Z, and due to the nature of the search I am receiving 121 rows. I want to be able to flag a duplicate as a pair of records, regardless of which way around they are paired.

A result may be listed as A and C match on field Z. I want it to then recognise that C and A as a match is a duplicate of A and C as a match.

I'm using the following code for the query

```
SELECT T1.ID AS ID1,
   T2.ID AS ID2,
   T1.X AS X1,
   T2.X AS X2,
   T1.Y AS Y1,
   T2.Y AS Y2,
   T1.Z AS Z1,
   T2.Z AS Z2
FROM (SELECT ID,
           X,
           Y,
           Z
      FROM TABLE) T1
   JOIN (SELECT ID,
                X,
                Y,
                Z
           FROM TABLE) T2
      ON    (   T1.X = T2.X
             OR T1.Y = T2.Y
             OR T1.Z = T2.Z)
         AND T1.ID <> T2.ID;
```

Comment: Select distinct is not appropriate for this query, as distinct will not detect instances where pair A and B is the same as pair B and A. It will only filter out where pair A and B is the same as pair A and B.

Answer (score 0):

To have each pair appear only once you could try changing the last line to

```
         AND T1.ID < T2.ID;
```

Comment: T1.ID < T2.ID has significantly reduced the number of records that are returned. Unfortunately in the case where A matches B-K on field Z, it will still return a result where B matches C, where C matches D, etc. I only want it to return B matches C if the conditions on which B matches C are different to the conditions on which A matches B, and A matches C.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use exists().

```
select < some columns >
  from table x as x1
 where exists (select 1
          from table x as x2
         where (x1.x = x2.x or x1.y = x2.y or x1.z = x2.z)
           and x1.id <> x2.id)
```